# Validar que una fecha sea real

Tags: bash, date

Tengo que hacer un script de Bash que valide si una fecha introducida por el usuario es real, entre otras cosas. Esto es lo que llevo hecho:

```
while ! $CONDITION # Niega la condición. false es true, true es false.
    do
        read -p "introduce una fecha. Debe seguir la forma 00/00/0000 - Día/Mes/Año " DATE

        if [[ $DATE =~ ^([0-9]{2}[/]){2}[0-9]{4}$ ]] # Se comprueba si la fecha cumple con los criterios
        then
            DIA=${DATE:0:2}
            MES=${DATE:3:2}
            ANO=${DATE:6:4}
            # Obtenemos las subcadenas del año, entres fracciones.


            if []

            CONDITION=true
        else
            echo "Fecha no correcto"
        fi
    done
```

Aunque no estoy seguro de cómo continuar. Había pensado en usar el comando `date` con las subcadena de la fecha (DIA, MES, ANO) y ver qué me devuelve; pero ni idea. Creo que hay una salida para errores o algo así, o quizás es más simple que todo eso. ¿Me podéis echa una mano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente puedes usar `date` directamente pasándole la fecha a comprobar con `-d "fecha"`. Silencia toda la salida y luego captura si el comando ha sido satisfactorio o no:

```
date -d "20220-02-33" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "si" || echo "no"
```

Que sería lo mismo que decir:

```
if date -d "20220-02-33" >/dev/null 2>&1; 
then
    echo "si"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Fíjate que incluso detecta los años bisiestos:

```
$ date -d "2020-02-29" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "si" || echo "no"
si
$ date -d "2021-02-29" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "si" || echo "no"
no
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Una pregunta, ¿las condiciones no deberían ir entre [[]] o []?

Comment: @Manuel en este caso es suficiente así, pruébalo :)

Comment: Perfecto, gracias